# How to create a singleton Custom UIView with XIB?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How to create a singleton Custom `UIView` with `XIB` that will be present in every `UIViewcontroller`, and if updated in any controller changes should be reflected in every `UIViewcontroller`? Same like Facebook setting page that is visible from every `UIViewcontroller`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What "changes"?  The type/position of UI elements or the data the view presents?

Comment: In my application, i have an admin page which ail appear whenever user will swipe from top left,just like Facebook. And User can update his setting in any view controller. So these changes that he made in one view controller should reflect when he goes in another view controller and swipe from top left to see his admin page.